# diff on Windows7 seems to be combining both paths

Tags: windows-7, diff, patch

I'm trying to run GnuWin32 `diff` on window7, to generate a patch file, and it keeps coming back with an error saying it can't find a file. Only the file it claims to be looking for isn't either one that I asked for: it's both of them.

```
>diff -r html_orig html_mod  
diff: html_orig/html_mod: No such file or directory
```

`html_orig` and `html_mod` are both directories. This works fine on Windows XP, but not Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, there's nothing wrong with `diff`, the problem was the operator. Your need the `-r` option when diffing directories.

Answer (score 0):

The `diff` provided by GnuWin is
[over 8 years old](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/diffutils/2.8.7-1).

I would strongly suggest using something more modern, perhaps
[`git diff`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I assume git diff can generate patches?

Comment: Uh...can you use git diff if you're not using git? It looks like it only works for git repositories.